# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning, but I am handling errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, promise, async-await

I'm getting the following error:

```
Houston we got an err at getGames in index.js
(node:72197) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>
(node:72197) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:72197) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
error at getGames rp
```

Here is the relevant code:

Helper function to get Data from API (rp is request-promise-native)

```
const getGames = async () => {
   return await rp(`https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetTopLiveGame/v1?key=${KEY}&partner=0`)
   .catch(err => console.log('error at getGames rp'))
   .error(err => console.log('actual error at getGames rp'))
}
```

I call this every 5 seconds

```
app.get('/api/update', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await getGames()
  .catch(err => console.log('Houston we got an err at getGames in index.js'))
  const dataJson = JSONbig.parse(data);

  if (dataJson.game_list && dataJson.game_list.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < dataJson.game_list.length; i++) {
      const game = dataJson.game_list[i];
...
```

The '/api/update' endpoint gets called every 5 seconds. I get the above error. My for loop stops iterating. I'd like it to skip the one it's error'ing on, but it's saying im not handling the error. I have catch blocks and even error blocks and I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

I've also tried manually calling:

```
`https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetTopLiveGame/v1?key=${KEY}&partner=0`
```

in postman many times in quick succession, but postman never errors out. So the issue is in my code somewhere. I've handled all errors so I can't seem to find what i'm not handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- Only catch at a point where you can *actually handle* the error. Here, you probably only want to catch in the `.get` callback (otherwise, if you `.catch` in `getGames`, you'll return a resolved Promise, not a rejected Promise)
- When an error occurs, don't try to parse the data (since it won't be populated) - trying to parse and iterate over it will result in more errors
- There's no point in having an `async` function that only has one `await` that immediately gets returned

```
const getGames = () => {
  return rp(`https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetTopLiveGame/v1?key=${KEY}&partner=0`);
};

app.get('/api/update', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await getGames()
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Houston we got an err at getGames in index.js');
      // handle error
    });
  if (!data) {
    // There was an error
    return;
  }
  const dataJson = JSONbig.parse(data);
  // rest of the code
});
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that really helped improved my understanding of error handling. However, I'm confused why my getGames function is error'ing? I manually did this API call in postman many times in quick succession, but i received data every time. Yet in my app it's error'ing.

Comment: Because *When an error occurs, don't try to parse the data (since it won't be populated) - trying to parse and iterate over it will result in more errors* - so, if there's no data (make sure not to return anything from the `.catch`), return

Comment: Also note that JSON notation is a format used to *represent an object or array in string format*. After deserialization, you only have a plain object or array, *not* a JSON - might be helpful to change the variable name from `dataJson` to `dataObj`, or something like that